# How to get color depth of DICOM pixel data in reliable way?

Tags: image-processing, colors, rgb, dicom

A DICOM file may have either uncompressed pixel data or [compressed pixel data](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/old/image_data_handlers.html). It's `PhotometricInterpretation (0028,0004)` can be MONOCHROME1/MONOCHROME2/RGB/PALETTE COLOR/YBR etc. There is also a [Pydicom page about color space](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/old/working_with_pixel_data.html#color-space).

But from these pages or any other DICOM websites, it is not clear to me that how to get the color depth.

Is either `BitsAllocated (0028,0100)` or `BitsStored (0028,0101)` tag referring to color depth? Can its color depth be different than these two tag values?

How to get color depth of DICOM pixel data in reliable way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bits Stored` is the number of bits that is used for the actual color or grayscale data, so it is at least related to the color depth. `Bits Allocated` is always a multiple of 8, as the data is always organized in bytes, where some of the upper bits may not be used for data (with the exception of Bit Data, where it is 1).

Getting the bit depth is not as straightforward as it may seem. While the number of bits used for the data can mostly be defined, the resolution of the data (e.g. the distance between adjacent values) may also depend on the `Photometric Interpretation`, and of course on the resolution provided by the modality itself.

The easiest case is monochrome data (`Photometric Interpretation` is `MONOCHROME1` or `MONOCHROME2`), where the color depth is directly defined by `Bits Stored` typical values being 12, 14 or 16. The same is mostly true for `RGB` data (e.g. data originally recorded as RGB), and while it is true that `Bits Stored` can have [different values](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part05.html#table_8.2.4-1) for JPEG2000 encoded images as correctly mentioned by @kritzel_sw, I yet have to see any `RGB` data with `Bits Stored` different from 8. *Update*: I still haven't seen this, but found that RTDOSE images [can have 32 Bits Stored](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part03.html#sect_C.8.8.3.4.2).

For color data in the YBR color space (`Photometric Interpretation` is `YBR_xxx`) this is less clear. It somewhat depends on your definition of color depth. Given that the used color space is YBR instead of RGB, and the number of bits used for each component maybe different (for example in `YBR_FULL_422`, which is used for some JPEG compressed images, 2 channels our downsampled), the resulting image if converted into RGB (what is mostly done) uses 8 bits for each color component, but the actual number of possible values is less than 256 for that reason. So if your definition of color depth depends on the number of bits used per RGB channel, the answer would probably be 8 in this case, but if you define the color depth per YBR channel, the answer could be different and depends both on the `Photometric Interpretation` and `Bits Stored`.

A special case is the `PhotometricInterpretation` of `PALETTE COLOR`, where the possible colors are defined in the color table. In this case, the number of colors per color component is defined in the first value of the [Palette Color Lookup Table Descriptor](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.7.6.3.html#sect_C.7.6.3.1.5) (0028,1101-1104), which is equal for all 3 tables (e.g. for the Red, Green and Blue components). The actual color depth has to be derived from that value.

Given all that the answer is probably: it depends. I'll also add the note by @kritzel_sw, that many of the IODs limit the degrees of freedom of how pixel data is encoded significantly, which will narrow down the possibilities for the color depth for any concrete type of images.

I'm interested if anybody has a more straightforward answer.

Comment: Admittedly it is very unlikely to find such images in reality but in theory, it is incorrect that Photometric Interpretation = RGB means "8 bits per channel". See here: http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part05.html#table_8.2.2-1

Comment: Thank you - you are right, of course. I adapted the answer a bit, and it gets more fuzzy which each correction... I may have another look later, as this is actually a bit complicated. The question is also, what the resulting color depth is used/needed for.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of pixel data encoding in DICOM. To waive all the complexity, I would like to mention that many of the IODs limit the degrees of freedom of how pixel data is encoded significantly. So unless the question comes in a context of a general purpose viewer, there is a lot of potential for simplification by narrowing the support for different types of images.

Comment: About "raw pixel data can be used independently from the LUT". I tend to disagree. There are some edge cases which may have a misleading description in the DICOM Standard. E.g. see groups.google.com/g/comp.protocols.dicom/c/qr_A0vUYrJs. However this does not refer to a Photometric Interpretation of PALETTE COLOR - just to avoid more confusion than inevitably necessary :-D
@scaramallion: Can you provide a reference in the standard that your statement was based on?

Comment: @kritzel_sw sorry yes I think you're correct. I was thinking of *Pixel Presentation* and things like psuedo-color softcopy IOD

Comment: @kritzel_sw thank you for pointing out this. From the nema site, RGB can have 16 Bits Stored case, does it mean that it is using 16 bit color depth? And yes, I'm trying to make a general viewer. Regarding "IODs limit the degrees of freedom of how pixel data is encoded significantly", is there any example?

Comment: @kritzel_sw, mrbean-bremen sorry that I response a little late, and I have one more question. Can I assume that the lowerest value pixel is pure black color? Is this question more like "what the resulting color depth is used/needed for" than a technicial issue?

Comment: No, that cannot be assumed. First, the pixel value does not directly define the color by itself, that is done by applying a LUT. Second, even without that, for MONOCHROME1 images the lowest pixel value is white, not black. And your second question: it is more about what do you mean by color depth, and what do you need it for, probably. In the answer the usual definition of bit depth was assumed.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thank you for the answer. To make it more clear, let me take an example to ask again. If a DICOM only has modality LUT transform, and it is just MONOCHROME2 and a normal CT scan. Its HU values after LUT are from [-100, 400]. To visualize this DICOM on an 8-bit monitor device, the 1st way is to map [-100, 400] to [0, 255],  the 2nd way is to map [-100, -100+Bits_Stored*Rescale Slope] to [0, 255], which way is correct or suitable?

Comment: Or even using "-100" as black color may not be correct? I mean, if another DICOM in the same series has [-300, 400] HU values, will it be weird that their black colors refer to different HU?  
Or should I find out a minimized value as black color among the same series if I want to treat them as 1 series and want to look forward and backward for comparison? Or is there any absolute CT HU value referring to black color?

Comment: There is no "correct" way. If there is no VOI LUT defined (and even if there is), it depends on your application what do you want to show. Sometimes it may make sense to use a LUT from minimum to maximum in the current image, sometimes it may be more sensible to use min/max of the whole series, or, as we are speaking about CT here, use just one of the standard W/L for the tissue (Lung, Bones, whatever) you are interested in, and ignore the pixel range. If that is not sufficient, I suggest you write a new question where you clarify what do you want to know.